# Problems in resetting timer

Tags: javascript, eventhandler

*Hello folks.*

*Currently having some problems in resetting timer in my auto logout app. When I add "mousemove" event it doesn't work correctly. I'd like some help with that.*
*This is my code:*

```css
body{
    text-align: center;
    background: #00ECB9;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
  }
  
  h1{
    color: #396;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: 40px 0px 20px;
  }
  
  #clockdiv{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  
  #clockdiv > div{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #00BF96;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  #clockdiv div > span{
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #00816A;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .smalltext{
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
    <a href="infoPage.html">Info Page</a>

    <h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
    <div id="clockdiv">
        <div>
            <span class="days"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="hours"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="minutes"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="seconds"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
            const total = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
            const seconds = Math.floor((total / 1000) % 60);
            const minutes = Math.floor((total / 1000 / 60) % 60);
            const hours = Math.floor((total / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
            const days = Math.floor(total / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

            return {
                total,
                days,
                hours,
                minutes,
                seconds
            };
        }

        function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
            const clock = document.getElementById(id);
            const daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
            const hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
            const minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
            const secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

            function updateClock() {
                const t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

                daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
                hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
                minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
                secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

                if (t.total <= 0) {
                    clearInterval(timeinterval);
                }
            }

            updateClock();
            const timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
        }

        const timeInMinutes = 10;
        const currentTime = Date.parse(new Date());
        const deadline = new Date(currentTime + timeInMinutes*60*1000);

        initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", e => { console.log("Your page is up.")});

        
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hello folks!

Currently having some problems in resetting time in my auto logout app. I'd like some help with that.

This is my code:

```css
body{
    text-align: center;
    background: #00ECB9;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
  }
  
  h1{
    color: #396;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: 40px 0px 20px;
  }
  
  #clockdiv{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  
  #clockdiv > div{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #00BF96;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  #clockdiv div > span{
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #00816A;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .smalltext{
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
    <a href="infoPage.html">Info Page</a>

    <h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
    <div id="clockdiv">
        <div>
            <span class="days"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="hours"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="minutes"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="seconds"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
            var total = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
            var seconds = Math.floor((total / 1000) % 60);
            var minutes = Math.floor((total / 1000 / 60) % 60);
            var hours = Math.floor((total / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
            var days = Math.floor(total / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

            return {
                total,
                days,
                hours,
                minutes,
                seconds
            };
        }

        function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
            var clock = document.getElementById(id);
            var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
            var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
            var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
            var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

            function updateClock() {
                var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

                daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
                hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
                minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
                secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

                if (t.total <= 0) {
                    clearInterval(timeinterval);
                } 
            }

            updateClock();
            var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
        }

        var timeInMinutes = 10;
        var currentTime = Date.parse(new Date());
        var deadline = new Date(currentTime + timeInMinutes * 60 * 1000);

        window.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer);
        initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);

        /*  window.addEventListener("mousemove", e => { 
              console.log('Hello!')
          }); */

        function resetTimer() {
            timeInMinutes = 10;
            currentTime = Date.parse(new Date());
            deadline = new Date(currentTime + timeInMinutes * 60 * 1000);
            initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);

        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You posted the code twice. Is there a difference?

Comment: Put the JavaScript in the bottom left box of the snippet editor, not the HTML box.

Comment: Each time you call `initializeClock()` you start a new interval timer, but you don't stop the old timer.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Comment: @Barmar I can see that. But, I'm not being capable to reset the timer without calling initializeClock( ) again.

Comment: So cancel the previous timer..... clearInterval()

Answer (score 0):

Make `timeinterval` a global variable. Then it will persist between calls to `initializeClock`, and you can clear it before starting another timer.

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var total = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((total / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((total / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((total / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(total / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

  return {
    total,
    days,
    hours,
    minutes,
    seconds
  };
}

var timeinterval;

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  clearInterval(timeinterval);
  timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var timeInMinutes = 10;
var currentTime = Date.parse(new Date());
var deadline = new Date(currentTime + timeInMinutes * 60 * 1000);

window.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);

/*  window.addEventListener("mousemove", e => { 
      console.log('Hello!')
  }); */

function resetTimer() {
  timeInMinutes = 10;
  currentTime = Date.parse(new Date());
  deadline = new Date(currentTime + timeInMinutes * 60 * 1000);
  initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);

}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #00ECB9;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

h1 {
  color: #396;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 40px 0px 20px;
}

#clockdiv {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#clockdiv>div {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #00BF96;
  display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div>span {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #00816A;
  display: inline-block;
}

.smalltext {
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
  <a href="infoPage.html">Info Page</a>

  <h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
  <div id="clockdiv">
    <div>
      <span class="days"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="hours"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="minutes"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="seconds"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks a lot by the help @Barmar!